# Grammy Winners Grading

Tags: pattern, word-property, anagram

### Prologue.

> I am bored. I have divided the Grammy winners in the past few years into the following tiers, according to a specific **and objective** criterion. How did I categorise them?

### The Classification -

**Tier 0**

> Swift, Smith

**Tier 1**

> Glover, Lipa, Hansen, Lewis

**Tier 2**

> Musgraves, Hernandez, Cara, Adkins, Bennett, Ronson, Sheeran, Trainor, Little, O'Connor, Haggerty

---

### Notes/ Clarification Section:

1) The artists above are all recorded by their real surnames. Please comment if you need any more examples and categorisation.

2) Please refrain from closing this as too broad. I will add more tags if necessary.

3) There is no [knowledge](/questions/tagged/knowledge) tag. No knowledge about the artists are needed.

4) Order of artists are not important as long as they are in that tier.

<sub>Working for [Generalist Countdown](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6657/generalist-countdown?cb=1) - [anagram](/questions/tagged/anagram)</sub>

### Thank you!!!

This question made it into the Puzzling Stack Exchange Newsletter (Monday, July 15, 2019) as part of the top questions! Couldn't be done without you guys! Thank you very, very much!!! :D

Comment: Would you like to indicate whether more than two tiers are possible? (I appreciate that the answer might well be that you would rather leave that open.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan yep that may be possible, but i have not found one such example

Comment: PSA: For reasons that may or may not be apparent, I wondered whether perhaps OK might be unaware that "glover" is an English word, and asked in TSL chat whether knowing that changed anything. The answer, just so that everyone knows, is that it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Adding to @[Parseltongue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/32249/parseltongue)'s answer, really, because his/her answer is really similar! Give that an upvote if you will to mine! (Also, the user needs one more upvote to make it past 500 rep :P)

---

I believe it has to do with

> **anagrams** considering that sounds like "grammy" and it is a tag for the Generalist Countdown

and how

> the tier number represents the minimum amount of words required to anagram it (though with the amount of anagrams available, I have only kept to the minimum anyway).

With that being said:

**Tier 0**

> There are **0** words in the anagrams of "Swift" and "Smith"

**Tier 1**

> There is **1** word in the anagrams of each of the names: 
>  Glover ~ grovel 
>  Lipa ~ pail 
>  Hansen ~ hennas 
>  Lewis ~ Wiles

**Tier 2**

> There are **2** words in the anagrams of each of the names in this category whether or not they make sense <s>(except for "Musgraves ~ sevrugas" but that is a rarely said word)</s>. 
> Musgraves ~ Grave sums [**Kacey Musgraves**] 
>  Hernandez ~ Harden Zen 
>  Cara ~ A car 
>  Adkins ~ is dank. [**Scott Adkins**] 
>  Bennett ~ Bent en 
>  Ronson ~ Nor son 
>  Sheeran ~ He's near! [**Ed Sheeran**] 
>  Trainor ~ ran riot [**Meghan Trainor**]
>  Little ~ Let lit 
>  O'Connor ~ No croon 
>  Haggerty ~ Ghat grey ~ They garg [but "garg" is slang for "very ugly man" apparently].

Comment: @OmegaKrypton How do you decide *objectively* what counts as an English word? (For example, why not [tillet](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tillet)?)

Comment: @Deusovi I hadn't found that word. I used [this anagram server](https://wordsmith.org/anagram/advanced.html) as my standard...

Comment: @Deusovi maybe cambridge dictionary can act as the standard, but since this puzzle was to find the method of categorisation, sadly i can't put this in the puzzle :(

Comment: Given Deusovi’s finding of tillet, perhaps Little ought to be in Tier 1....

Comment: @El-Guest it isnt in the cambridge dictionary, and it is arguably a word... idk :P

Answer (score 10):

This is absolutely absurd, but here it goes:

Tier 0:

> Are names that are scrabble-valid words on their own, and cannot be re-arranged to construct words of the same length as the original.

Tier 1:

> Are names that may or may not be scrabble-valid words on their own, but CAN be re-arranged to construct words of the same length as the original, `e.g. grovel, pail, hennas, wiles`

Tier 2:

> Are names that CANNOT be re-arranged to construct scrabble-valid words of the same length as the original (little doesn't count because it's not a re-arrangement), but you can re-construct words of n-2 length from the originals.  `e.g. graves, hennaed, aa, been, nor, hens, anti, tell, corn, earthy`

Comment: Not 100% convinced, but this would explain the use of "grammy" in the title :)

Comment: Ha! I'm not convinced either.

Comment: On this theory, why exactly is LITTLE not in tier 0? (I think _something like_ this has to be right, but it doesn't seem like it works yet.)

Answer (score 2):

### Making of "Grammy Winners Grading" - <sub>SPOILERS ALERT!!</sub>

[This sort of answers are allowed by the community](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5420/sharing-and-rewarding-what-went-into-making-a-good-puzzle/5442#5442)

**Idea Construction**

I was planning to make a What is a ??? Word<sup>TM</sup> Puzzle, and have decided on the theme of using anagrams, since this, I believe, is a rather innovative idea.

**Hint Words**

I then looked for a word to describe these words, and realised Grammy might be a good choice. I then looked for winners of Grammy awards over the years, looking for anagrams through [this anagram server](https://wordsmith.org/anagram/advanced.html).

**Difficulty Encountered**

I looked through the winners for 4 ~ 5 years of Grammy Awards, and it turned out that too few names can be anagrammed (only 4 so far). I then decided to divert this into a tier classification, with tiers numbered to denote the minimum number of words that can anagram to that surname.

**And Voila! This is the Birth of the Grammy Winners Grading puzzle, and I hope you have enjoyed it!**

Comment: I also wanted to make a Word$^{\verb|TM|}$ puzzle.... in the midst of completing one, now, actually. But thanks for the green tick! :D